# Import XSL Sheets one at a time

Tags: xml, xslt

XSL has an element called `<xsl:import href="" />` with which you can apply `n` number of other existing XSL sheets. However... using `<xsl:apply-imports />` is not desirable to me as in between each imported stylesheet I want to insert new HTML code (our XSL sheets format the data as HTML). Is there a way to import each stylesheet one at a time so I can insert HTML code in between each import?

Comment: An example would be helpful to understand what you're trying to do. So far there seems to be some confusion between *importing* stylesheets and *applying* imported templates. Those two things happen at different times and have different effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of what you're seeking to accomplish would help, but perhaps you can achieve your desired result using `xs:include`, which can appear at any point in the top-level.  See "[Tip: Use imports and includes to override XSLT templates](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipimpinc/index.html)" for a good overview of `xs:import` vs `xs:include`.  See also the "[Combining Stylesheets](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Combining-Stylesheets)" in the [**XSLT 1.0** Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt).

**For XSLT 2.0**, for conditional inclusion, consider the [`xsl:use-when`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#conditional-inclusion) attribute, which can be added to `xs:import` (or `xs:include` or any other XSLT instruction).

Comment: I didn't realize there was an include element as well. What's the difference between them? (e.g. is there any real reason to use one over the other due to behavioral differences?)

Comment: See the included reference for `xs:include` vs `xs:import` but very roughly: Use `xs:include` to bring in another stylesheet as a part of the one you're writing; use `xs:import` to bring in another stylesheet like the one you're writing. There's more details to be aware of, so read the mentioned developerWorks article. Another classic reference on the topic is Bob DuCharme's "Combining Stylesheets with Include and Import" http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/11/01/xslt/